# Android: how to replace/delete a fragment inside section pager adapter in TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

:)

I'm writing an Android app which do a lot of things, but i have an issue with java GUI code and i'm not able to go on.

What I would like to achieve is a TabLayout gui user-editable. The user could add , remove or modify section. I write all the code that let me add section. To do this i used a Section Pager Adapter as shown

```
class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public ArrayList<Fragment> mfragList;
public ArrayList<String> mfragtit;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<Fragment> mFragList, ArrayList<String> mFragTit) {
    super(fm);
    this.mfragList=mFragList;
    this.mfragtit=mFragTit;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.mfragList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.mfragList.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    return this.mfragtit.get(position);
}

public void addFrag(Fragment frag, String tit){
    this.mfragList.add(frag);
    this.mfragtit.add(tit);

}

public void delFrag(int index){
    this.mfragList.remove(index-1);
    this.mfragtit.remove(index-1);
}
}
```

Well, i'm new in Android and what i've understand about this code is that this class, when called, takes two Arraylist: **mfragList** and **mfragtit** which contains the fragment of each section and its title. Then when this adapter is created it is set as the adapter of view pager, which it should be the object that contain the view.

So I get the first issue when i tried to delete one section. To do this i thought to delete both title and fragment from adapter, then notifydatasetChanged and then set again the adapter for the view pager. But it actually don't works (even if I only notifydatasetChanged while don't set adapter again).

What I do in MainActivity is something like this:

```
                        ad.delFrag(parseInt(elim_i)+1); //ad is the adapter declared as field 
                        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mViewPager.setAdapter(ad);
                        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

The issue was that it delete the right title but the wrong fragment, infact it ever delete the last fragment in **mfragList**

Any help gonna be appreciated.

Thank you guys.

Nico

Answer (score 0):

FragmentAdapter internal have cache with loaded fragment. So that it's behaving like this. Try this adapter

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> title = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i =0; i < 3; i++) {
            fragmentList.add(new SampleViewPagerFragment());
            title.add("Fragment #" + i);
        }

        final CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(fragmentList, title);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.removeFragmentAtPosition(2);
            }
        }, 3000);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.addFragmentToAdapter("Title", new SampleViewPagerFragment());
            }
        }, 6000);

    }


    private static class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<String> mTitle = new ArrayList<>();

        CustomPagerAdapter(List<Fragment> mFragmentList, List<String> mTitle) {
            this.mFragmentList = mFragmentList;
            this.mTitle = mTitle;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            container.removeViewAt(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mTitle.get(0);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return (view == object);
        }


        void removeFragmentAtPosition(int position) {
            mTitle.remove(position);
            mFragmentList.remove(position);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        void addFragmentToAdapter(String title, Fragment fragment) {
            mTitle.add(title);
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Vin and thank you very much for your answer. I tried out your adapter but i found some issues. First of all, it seems that the method calls isViewFromObject doesn't let the adapter (or viewpager) to show the fragment; (i tried it adding each fragment by a function calls from pushbutton). So comment out that method and tried again, but i get other issue: when try to add a third fragment the app crash.

Comment: @NicolaBarlabà So you're getting error only when you try to add new Fragment ?

Comment: i get error if i don't delete the isViewFromObject method (), and if i delete that, I still get an error when add third fragment (section)

Comment: @NicolaBarlabà check the updated program it'll add new fragment and delete fragment from list

Comment: ya i see it but it still have isViewFromObject which doesn't let adapter show fragment as i told you. Moreover in my application i need to let users add fragment, so i call addFrag method from pushbutton. When the user (me) add the first frag it works, second frag it works, third it crash! So i don't understand how the updated code could solve this issue.

Comment: I found some difference in my adapter, 1) my class isn't public and isn't static. Is just class SectionPagerAdapter... could be this a problem? 2) does the override method order matter? because mine is different

Comment: @NicolaBarlabà please use completely this adapter because other Adapter has a internal cache so it won't work

Comment: another difference is that mine adapter constructor takes fragment manager and do super() method. Your doesn't have it

Comment: Yes it's customised version..,

Comment: Ok sorry, i'm gonna try again

Comment: ok i tried it out, used completely your adapter just copied in new class file but it doesn't work: it doesn't show the fragment when created. now i can't comment out isViewFromObject method

Comment: Run the complete project and check it's working from you I mean only using my code first

Comment: i'm trying to do it, but i get a lot of error when i create a new project and copy this code